# Slime Autocompletion when editing file

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, common-lisp, slime

I am new to Lisp. I installed LIsp in a box to learn Common Lisp. In the `slime-repl` I can use autocompletion using the tab key. However I want to do so in other buffers - files - I edit. For instance I want to do the following:

```
C-x b  ;; Here I switch to the buffer corresponding to my file. S I am not in the repl anymore.
(remove-i  ;; Here I use the tab key, but nothing occurs.
```

In the repl buffer, I can type `(remove-i` and I will see matching functions such as `remove-if` and `remove-if-not`.

How can I add lisp autocompletion while editing any other file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
C-M-i (translated from <M-tab>) runs the command slime-complete-symbol (found
in slime-mode-indirect-map), which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
‘slime.el’.

It is bound to C-c TAB, C-M-i, <menu-bar> <SLIME> <Complete Symbol>.

(slime-complete-symbol)

Complete the symbol at point.

Completion is performed by ‘slime-completion-at-point-functions’.
```

You can bind this function to TAB, if you want.

Peter